# return value on button Datatable Server-Side

Tags: php, mysqli, datatables, server-side

So guys, how can i put a button in my column this form:

**Protcolo** **Assunto** **Action**
001 lalalalala print

Im using datatable server-side:

```
<table id="datatable_fixed_column" class="table table-striped table-bordered" width="100%">
<thead>
<tr>                                            
<th>Protocolo</th>
<th>Assunto</th>
<th>Action</th>                                                                                          
</tr>
</thead>                                    
</table>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() {

        var otable = $('#datatable_fixed_column').DataTable({

        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "ajax": "server_processing/protocolos.php",

        "order": [[ 0, "asc" ]],

        "columnDefs": [
        { "width": "10%", "targets": 0 },
        { "width": "70%", "targets": 1 },
        { "width": "20%", "targets": 2 }
        ],

        columns: [
            { data: "protocolo" },
            { data: "assunto" },           
            {
                data: null,
                defaultContent: '<form method="post" action=""><input type="hidden" id="idcontrib" name="idcontrib" value="id_protocolo"><button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning btn-xs" name="edit_contrib">Editar</button> &nbsp;&nbsp; <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" name="exc_contrib">Excluir</button></form>'
            }           
        ],

        "sDom": "<'dt-toolbar'<'col-xs-6'f><'col-xs-6'<'toolbar'>>r>"+
                "t"+
                "<'dt-toolbar-footer'<'col-xs-6'i><'col-xs-6'p>>"
        });

         $("div.toolbar").html('<div class="text-right"><img src="img/logo2.png" alt="SmartAdmin" style="width: 111px; margin-top: 3px; margin-right: 10px;"></div>');

    })

</script>
```

**protocolos.php**

```
<?php 
$table = 'tbl_protocolos_teste';
$primaryKey = 'id_protocolo';

$columns = array(
array( 'db' => 'protocolo', 'dt' => 0 ),
array( 'db' => 'assunto',  'dt' => 1 ),
array( 'db' => 'id_protocolo',  'dt' => 2 )
);

$sql_details = array(
'user' => 'root',
'pass' => '$#$#$#',
'db'   => 'bbbb',
'host' => 'localhost'
);

require( 'ssp.class.php' );

echo json_encode(
SSP::simple( $_GET, $sql_details, $table, $primaryKey, $columns )
);
```

**ssp.class.php**

```
<?php

class SSP {

static function data_output ( $columns, $data )
{
$out = array();

for ( $i=0, $ien=count($data) ; $i<$ien ; $i++ ) {
$row = array();

for ( $j=0, $jen=count($columns) ; $j<$jen ; $j++ ) {
$column = $columns[$j];

// Is there a formatter?
if ( isset( $column['formatter'] ) ) {
$row[ $column['dt'] ] = $column['formatter']( $data[$i][ $column['db'] ], $data[$i] );
}
else {
$row[ $column['dt'] ] = $data[$i][ $columns[$j]['db'] ];
}
}

$out[] = $row;
}

return $out;
}

static function limit ( $request, $columns )
{
$limit = '';

if ( isset($request['start']) && $request['length'] != -1 ) {
$limit = "LIMIT ".intval($request['start']).", ".intval($request['length']);
}

return $limit;
}

static function order ( $request, $columns )
{
$order = '';

if ( isset($request['order']) && count($request['order']) ) {
$orderBy = array();
$dtColumns = self::pluck( $columns, 'dt' );

for ( $i=0, $ien=count($request['order']) ; $i<$ien ; $i++ ) {
// Convert the column index into the column data property
$columnIdx = intval($request['order'][$i]['column']);
$requestColumn = $request['columns'][$columnIdx];

$columnIdx = array_search( $requestColumn['data'], $dtColumns );
$column = $columns[ $columnIdx ];

if ( $requestColumn['orderable'] == 'true' ) {
$dir = $request['order'][$i]['dir'] === 'asc' ?
'ASC' :
'DESC';

$orderBy[] = '`'.$column['db'].'` '.$dir;
}
}

$order = 'ORDER BY '.implode(', ', $orderBy);
}

return $order;
}

static function filter ( $request, $columns, &$bindings )
{
$globalSearch = array();
$columnSearch = array();
$dtColumns = self::pluck( $columns, 'dt' );

if ( isset($request['search']) && $request['search']['value'] != '' ) {
$str = $request['search']['value'];

for ( $i=0, $ien=count($request['columns']) ; $i<$ien ; $i++ ) {
$requestColumn = $request['columns'][$i];
$columnIdx = array_search( $requestColumn['data'], $dtColumns );
$column = $columns[ $columnIdx ];

if ( $requestColumn['searchable'] == 'true' ) {
$binding = self::bind( $bindings, '%'.$str.'%', PDO::PARAM_STR );
$globalSearch[] = "`".$column['db']."` LIKE ".$binding;
}
}
}

// Individual column filtering
for ( $i=0, $ien=count($request['columns']) ; $i<$ien ; $i++ ) {
$requestColumn = $request['columns'][$i];
$columnIdx = array_search( $requestColumn['data'], $dtColumns );
$column = $columns[ $columnIdx ];

$str = $requestColumn['search']['value'];

if ( $requestColumn['searchable'] == 'true' &&
$str != '' ) {
$binding = self::bind( $bindings, '%'.$str.'%', PDO::PARAM_STR );
$columnSearch[] = "`".$column['db']."` LIKE ".$binding;
}
}

// Combine the filters into a single string
$where = '';

if ( count( $globalSearch ) ) {
$where = '('.implode(' OR ', $globalSearch).')';
}

if ( count( $columnSearch ) ) {
$where = $where === '' ?
implode(' AND ', $columnSearch) :
$where .' AND '. implode(' AND ', $columnSearch);
}

if ( $where !== '' ) {
$where = 'WHERE '.$where;
}

return $where;
}

static function simple ( $request, $sql_details, $table, $primaryKey, $columns )
{
$bindings = array();
$db = self::sql_connect( $sql_details );

// Build the SQL query string from the request
$limit = self::limit( $request, $columns );
$order = self::order( $request, $columns );
$where = self::filter( $request, $columns, $bindings );

// Main query to actually get the data
$data = self::sql_exec( $db, $bindings,
"SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS `".implode("`, `", self::pluck($columns, 'db'))."`
FROM `$table`
$where
$order
$limit"
);

// Data set length after filtering
$resFilterLength = self::sql_exec( $db,
"SELECT FOUND_ROWS()"
);
$recordsFiltered = $resFilterLength[0][0];

// Total data set length
$resTotalLength = self::sql_exec( $db,
"SELECT COUNT(`{$primaryKey}`)
FROM   `$table`"
);
$recordsTotal = $resTotalLength[0][0];


/*
* Output
*/
return array(
"draw"            => intval( $request['draw'] ),
"recordsTotal"    => intval( $recordsTotal ),
"recordsFiltered" => intval( $recordsFiltered ),
"data"            => self::data_output( $columns, $data )
);
}

static function sql_connect ( $sql_details )
{
try {
$db = @new PDO(
"mysql:host={$sql_details['host']};dbname={$sql_details['db']}",
$sql_details['user'],
$sql_details['pass'],
array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8")
);
}
catch (PDOException $e) {
self::fatal(
"An error occurred while connecting to the database. ".
"The error reported by the server was: ".$e->getMessage()
);
}

return $db;
}

static function sql_exec ( $db, $bindings, $sql=null )
{
// Argument shifting
if ( $sql === null ) {
$sql = $bindings;
}

$stmt = $db->prepare( $sql );
//echo $sql;

// Bind parameters
if ( is_array( $bindings ) ) {
for ( $i=0, $ien=count($bindings) ; $i<$ien ; $i++ ) {
$binding = $bindings[$i];
$stmt->bindValue( $binding['key'], $binding['val'], $binding['type'] );
}
}

// Execute
try {
$stmt->execute();
}
catch (PDOException $e) {
self::fatal( "An SQL error occurred: ".$e->getMessage() );
}

// Return all
return $stmt->fetchAll();
}

static function fatal ( $msg )
{
echo json_encode( array( 
"error" => $msg
) );

exit(0);
}

static function bind ( &$a, $val, $type )
{
$key = ':binding_'.count( $a );

$a[] = array(
'key' => $key,
'val' => $val,
'type' => $type
);

return $key;
}

static function pluck ( $a, $prop )
{
$out = array();

for ( $i=0, $len=count($a) ; $i<$len ; $i++ ) {
$out[] = $a[$i][$prop];
}

return $out;
}
}
```

my problem, 
first
the value protocolo and assunto **They are not being loaded**

```
{ data: "protocolo" },
{ data: "assunto" },
```

Second

How do I load the id_protocolo value in hidden field ?

```
<input type="hidden" id="idcontrib" name="idcontrib" value="id_protocolo">
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using the jQuery "DataTables" plugin.  In fact, both your jQuery and server code look like they're based on the sample code from the documentation (at www.datatables.net).

The first thing I would check is whether your jQuery is even talking to your server.  Is it even seeing "server_processing/protocolos.php"?

The best way to do this is to scale your code back to the bare minimum number of lines - just to test if the connection is happening.  In the documentation, they have some JavaScript like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() { $('#example').dataTable( { "processing": true, "serverSide": true, "ajax": "scripts/server_processing.php" } ); } );
```

I would start with this and try to get a "hello world" coming back from the server script.  Until you know that any sort of data is coming back from the server, it's difficult to tell what might be working in the code.

Comment: Without this it works.
`columns: [
  { data: "protocolo" },
  { data: "assunto" },           
  {
   data: null,
   defaultContent: '<form method="post" action=""><input  type="hidden" id="idcontrib" name="idcontrib" value="id_protocolo"><button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning btn-xs" name="edit_contrib">Editar</button> &nbsp;&nbsp; <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" name="exc_contrib">Excluir</button></form>'
 }           
],`
But i need add a button in the table. Editar e Excluir

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED

SCRIPT

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var otable = $('#datatable_fixed_column').DataTable({

"processing": true,
"serverSide": true,
"ajax": "server_processing/contribuintes.php",

"order": [[ 2, "asc" ]],

"columnDefs": [

    { "width": "5%", "targets": 0 },
    { "width": "10%", "targets": 1 },
    { "width": "15%", "targets": 2 },
    { "width": "20%", "targets": 3 },
    { "width": "10%", "targets": 4 },
    { "width": "20%", "targets": 5 },
    { "width": "5%", "targets": 6 },
    { "render": actionlinks,
      "data": null,         
      "targets": [7], "width": "15%", "targets": 7 },

],

});

function actionlinks(data, type, full) {

    return '<form method="post" action=""><input type="hidden" id="idcontrib" name="idcontrib" value="' + full[0] + '"><button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning btn-xs" name="edit_contrib">Editar</button>&nbsp;&nbsp;<button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" name="exc_contrib">Excluir</button>&nbsp;&nbsp;<button type="submit" class="btn btn-info btn-xs" name="ativa_contrib">Reativar</button></form> ';

}
```

TABLE

```
<table id="datatable_fixed_column" class="table table-striped table-bordered" width="100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>CPF</th>
      <th>Nome</th>
      <th>Sobrenome</th>
      <th>Celular</th>
      <th>email</th>
      <th>status</th>
      <th>Ação</th>                                                                                     
   </tr>
</thead>                                            
</table>
```

SERVER-SIDE

```
$table = 'tbl_contribuintes';
$primaryKey = 'id_contrib';

$columns = array(

array( 'db' => 'id_contrib', 'dt' => 0 ),
array( 'db' => 'cpf', 'dt' => 1 ),
array( 'db' => 'fnome',  'dt' => 2 ),
array( 'db' => 'lnome',  'dt' => 3 ),   
array( 'db' => 'celular1',  'dt' => 4 ),
array( 'db' => 'email',  'dt' => 5 ),
array( 'db' => 'id_status',  'dt' => 6 ),

);

$sql_details = array(
'user' => 'root',
'pass' => 'XXX',
'db'   => 'XXX',
'host' => 'localhost'
);

require( 'ssp.class.php' );

echo json_encode(
SSP::simple( $_GET, $sql_details, $table, $primaryKey, $columns )
);
```

tks Anderson Torres

http://andersontorres.com.br/